# Visual Studio: Creating Folders With Specified Name

Tags: visual-studio, installation, custom-action

I need to have some actions in the installer to create a folder and some subfolders. The folders aren't related to where the installation occurs or any standard folder but a specified name (e.g. c:\mediacentre).

I guess one option is to use a custom action, but is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

Right click "File System on Target Machine" — "add special folder" — "custom folder".

Rename the new custom folder, right click it — "properties".

In the properties editor window, set "always create" to true. Set "defaultlocation" to the desired folder path.